# What is the best way to shrink HD Quicktime MOV files

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, video, transcode

I recently purchased one of the Kodak Playsport cameras which takes 720p video @ 60 frames per second.

The video quality is great but the files are rather large for uploading to Youtube (about 150 Megs per minute of video). The files are output as Quicktime MOV files.

My question is:

Is there a command-line tool that allows me to shrink the video down to a lower resolution/size for quicker uploading? I'm thinking something like ImageMagick's convert but for video.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number video transcoders that you could use to covert mov files to different formats suitable for uploading. [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) is a popular one that has both a GUI and command-line version (`handbrake-gtk` or `handbrake-cli`). To use Handbreak on Ubuntu, you need to add a PPA:

https://edge.launchpad.net/~handbrake-ubuntu/+archive/ppa or the more current https://launchpad.net/~stebbins/+archive/ubuntu/handbrake-releases

I personally like, [transmageddon](http://www.linuxrising.org/) which is a GUI app with nice simple pre-sets. It's available in the archives.

[image: transmageddon]

Another option is [arista](http://www.transcoder.org/), another GUI transcoder available in the archives. In fact, it is a "Featured Application" in Ubuntu Software Center.

`ffmpeg` is another command line option that offers a lot of flexibility but can be a bit complex.

Comment: Good answer. I totally forgot about ffmpeg although both of the gui based apps look good too.

Comment: WinFF is a front end to ffmpeg and it converts anything to anything.

Comment: This answer is still helpful! Transmageddon is a wonderful tool!

Comment: Unfortunately in their stupidity Youtube has began erroring out when given theora stream. So, while it is a correct answer, it may be not useful for Youtube uploader.

Answer (score 5):

I use those options with ffmpeg (example with a video of 1m40s of 725MB 4096x2304):

MP4 conversion, Medium video quality with sound codec aac(245MB):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac output.mp4
```

MP4 conversion, Medium video quality with sound codec mp2(218MB):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec mp2 output.mp4
```

Avi conversion, Low quality (120MB)

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov b.avi
```

In addition you can reduce resolution with option

```
-vf scale=1024:576
```

MP4 conversion, Medium video quality with sound codec aac with rescaling (21MB):

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -preset fast -profile:v main -acodec aac -vf scale=1024:576 output.mp4
```