# How do I use mp4mux to create mp4 as recommended by Pitivi?

Tags: video, video-editor, pitivi

I'm trying to export video for use with the HTML5  tag. I've already created a nice webm encoding but can't create the equivalent mp4 video.

The MP4 option in Pitivi says it's not recommended and produces corrupted MP4 video when I use it. It recommends using mp4mux to render the project instead, but I can't find this option anywhere and Google is failing me.

How do I enable mp4mux rendering of MP4 in Pitivi?

Comment: I won't place an answer in order not to receive a downvote because of this may not give the right answer to your question but transcoding may be useful for you. You render your video in whatever lossless format you wish (AVI, MPG, etc.) and transcode it changing the video bit rate in order to make it usable for HTML5 <video src=""> tag. Further information and a GUI I gave when answering this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files - Good Luck!

Comment: @Geppettvs D'Constanzo -- add this as an answer and I'll upvote it. It answers the question, even if it isn't exactly the method Mark preferred.

Comment: Thank you for your cheer up djeikyb. I already posted my answer but what really cheers up is that people find useful what we do over here.

Answer (score 2):

Even if this may not give the right answer to your question, I put my answer here as requested by djeikyb:

Transcoding may be useful for you.

You render your video in whatever lossless format you wish (AVI, MPG, etc.) and transcode it changing the video bit rate in order to make it usable for HTML5  tag. Further information and a GUI I gave when answering this: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files) which I paste here for your convenience.

Good Luck!

> WOW!
>
> H264 is a high quality video codec but
>   (as you refer), it makes "heavy" size
>   video files.
>
> I am not sure if your question is
>   related to a GUI or Command Line task.
>   But, assumming that you are using
>   "Transmaggedon" I will write this
>   considering the options for GUI
>   applications.
>
> In my case, I prefer the usage of
>   "Mobile Media Converter" which works
>   pretty fine in 32bit systems (both
>   Ubuntu and MS based systems).
>   Unfortunatelly, it has its own
>   problems in 64 bit systems.
>
> What you wish is to make smaller size
>   video files. Which can be done by
>   changing the "video bit rate", which
>   will give you the best quality,
>   according to the video bit rate you
>   request. In example: a 40MB video file
>   (uncompressed, AVI) will fit in a 5MB
>   video file (any codec) if you use a
>   800kbps video bit rate. But -of
>   course- it may harm the quality.
>
> I strongly suggest you to perform some
>   testing using the Mobile Media
>   Converter, which can be reached (.deb)
>   by clicking the next link:
>
> http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm
>
> After installing, just drop any video
>   files (preferably small for the test)
>   into the drag and drop area, then open
>   the Advanced options by clicking a
>   small arrow that is placed at the very
>   right of the window, below the
>   "browse" button. "[ ... ]"
>
> Next, click in "Advanced" and you will
>   have all the options that you need in
>   order to transcode your video and make
>   small and good quality
>   transcodification.
>
> Remember: The higher video bit rate
>   is, you will have better quality but
>   the file size will become "heavier".
>
> *BTW: You can also transcode videos by using a non linear editing system,
>   such as "Kdenlive"
>   (http://www.kdenlive.org/) or
>   "Openshot"
>   (http://www.openshotvideo.com/) and
>   many more. A non linear editing system
>   will also be useful to edit the video
>   (trim, crop, add text and more).*
>
> Good luck!
>
> Here is a screenshot for you to see a
>   few options of Mobile Media Converter
>   in action.

[image]

Comment: Hi Geppettvs, thanks for the answer. I managed to get it to work by playing with the settings enough to encode my video but I'll keep transcoding in mind in the future.