# Music player incorrectly identifies downloaded music as "streaming"

Tags: music, multimedia

I am playing some music that I got from youtube.  On both movie player and Rhythmbox music player at the bottom of the movie player it says "streaming".

It doesn't let me control it -- I can't drag around the play head to different parts in the music -- but it will let me pause, play, or stop.

Why doesn't this file let me move around in the track like a normal music file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the sync of your music file is corrupted. Try transcoding and see what happen.

This behavior usually happens (but not limits to) when the audio inside of the file is using a variable bit rate (VBR) for the playback. So I suggest you to use a Constant Bit Rate (CBR) for the transcodification.

128 kbps will be good enough for the majority of the music genres. But if you are more exigent on the sounds that your compressed files delivers, try using 196~256 kbps CBR.

Please inform of your results in order to check if we can have a better answer.

Good luck!

P.S. This answer is for a video file transcoding, which is also the same rules for audio files and may be useful for you: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532)

Comment: i went to the software center and searched MP3 and i downloaded this plugin GStreamer extra plugins and installed it then log out and back in and (STREAMING) is gone thanks for the help