# How to convert Windows/Mac operating systems created, MPG file to Linux compatible file?

Tags: 11.04, video, vlc, ffmpeg

I have one file Film.MPG. Which is 720P and 50 frames per second. When i play the file using `gst-launch playbin uri=file:///tmp/final.mpg` it does not work. But it works with Mplayer/VLC. I noticed that I can convert the file and it also works but then I lose quality.

So my question is. How do i use `ffmpeg` to convert File.MPG to better quality File.AVI or other formats, so that I have balanced video/audio or almost same working.

Follow up:

by doing this its working: `ffmpeg -sameq -i filmfr2.mpg filmfr2.avi`

Comment: I doubt you could use ffmpeg to get better quality. If you transcode you always lose quality.

Comment: Silly question maybe, but have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras? That pulls in a lot of codecs not installed by default; yours might be among them.

Comment: @google - if this is the solution in your latest edit - then add an answer - in a few hours time, you should accept it.  If you do this, I'll even upvote you.  Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increasing the bitrate while preserving resolution and playback fps may result in a bigger file but you can save much of the quality. It's about to try it. There are also several GUIs for  ffmpeg, such as the Mobile Media Converter, mentioned over here for a question similar to this: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532)

Remember, this won't increase the quality of your video, but this can help you to preserve your current quality.

I hope this gives you a clue on how to run your test, even if this doesn't answer your question.

I expect downvotes to this answer, let's see how much do I harvest this time.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks by using this works: ffmpeg -sameq -i filmfr2.mpg filmfr2.avi

Answer (score 0):

If the file does not play under `gst-launch`, then you don't have the GStreamer elements necessary to play the file installed.

I would suggest trying to play the file under `totem` (which uses the GStreamer framework).  If there are any missing elements, it will pop up a window prompting you to install the packages necessary to play the file.  Once you've done that, the file should play in `totem` and any other GStreamer application (including a custom `gst-launch` invocation).