# How to convert a mp4 video to MPEG-1 Layer 1?

Tags: video, conversion

I need to convert a video to MPEG-1 Layer 1 to make some tests with the software I'm developing. How can I do this conversion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [ffmpeg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ffmpeg) [image: Install ffmpeg]

can do this easily from command line

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mpeg
```

There are felt one million [additional options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/ffmpeg.1.html) to change the output format.

Answer (score 2):

`ffmpeg` has since been deprecated. Use `avconv` instead. Same invocation:

> `avconv -i input.mp4 output.mpeg`

Comment: Not true anymore, ffmpeg is still the way to go now.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files/25532#25532) Which may be helpful for understanding the transcoding process.

There are several GUI's that are able to perform this task, which includes but not limits to:

## [Mobile Media Converter](http://www.miksoft.net/mobileMediaConverter.htm)

[image]

## [WinFF](http://winff.org/html_new/)

[image]

And [many more](http://alternativeto.net/software/handbrake/?platform=linux).

My favorite is the Mobile Media Converter but I have used the WinFF, Transmaggedon, Arista Transcoder, and many more in the past with excellent results.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg's .mpeg conversion gives you MPEG-1 Layer 2 audio.

ffmpeg doesn't have a layer 1 encoder.