# How Can I use Arista Transcoder or Transmageddon to shrink Videos?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor, transcode

How Can I use Arista Transcoder or Transmageddon to shrink a Video file?
Any other recommendation for a software that can shrink videos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accepted answer to this question shows a very detailed way of minimizing video size using Mobile Media Converter: [How can I maximum compress video files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25514/how-can-i-maximum-compress-video-files)

You can also use Arista Transcoder.The best compromise between quality and file size should be a mpeg4 file with xvid encoding.

Handbrake is also a decent application for video encoding (and superb for DVD ripping). A tutorial of minimizing file size is here on Youtube: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLVBb4zSdDo

Answer (score 0):

I think the application called VLC will do this. Just type VLC in the search box in the Ubuntu Software Centre, and install it from there. Good luck.

Comment: Can you put some more detail into it.