# editing videos avoiding change in format and resolution

Tags: video-editor

I am recording screencasts with ffmpeg(*), and editing them with kdenlive(**)

I have a problem: My videos often look much less sharp after rendering by kdenlive. I have to choose both a video profile and a rendering profile, and I am not sure I found the adequate ones.

First: Do I really have to choose profiles and such ? Is there a way to produce the cuts just keeping the resolution of the original (maybe with another software ?) ? I work with videos with the same resolution and sound, all the time

If not: What are the best profiles for me, considering quality ?

(*)  ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s 800x450 -i :0.0+26,65 -f alsa  -i plughw:1,0 -vcodec libx264 -crf 0 -preset ultrafast -acodec pcm_s16le video.mkv

(**) video profile 1024:576 PAL, 
     rendering profile 1280:720 youtube, dowloaded from kdenlive itself

Answer (score 1):

Parts of this answer comes from: [Downsize video for use on Android phone](https://askubuntu.com/a/178594/9598)

It is about the bitrate itself. You can change it in kdenlive by creating a new custom render profile.

Transcoding will reduce the bitrate as in your case, thus the file size, but preserving the video scale/aspect ratio/size. Anyway, reducing the bitrate may harm quality if you exceed the limits.

Once understood the last, if you increase the bitrate, preserving the video scale/aspect ratio/size, you will get better quality but also a bigger file size.

Follow the instructions in this kde wiki/manual related to [**Create custom render profiles**](http://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Project_Menu/Render#Create_Custom_Render_Profiles) in order to learn how to add a new profile to the list, after which you can include the details of your profile. Make sure you add the `maxrate` value in order to be able to include your desired maximum bitrate and this way get the best quality in kdenlive.

As recommended in the wiki page, I suggest you to also take a look at the [Render Profile Parameters - How to read them](http://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Project_Menu/Render/Render_Profile_Parameters) so that you can be able to add the proper parameters to your new profile.

Anything above 10000kbps should give you a good quality video file but you may wish to go for 15000k, 25000k or so in order to get broadcast quality.

BTW: You can also change the video and audio bitrates separately if you wish in order to keep sound quality.

Good luck!